# Losing Internet connection

Tags: 10.04, wireless, connection

I've recently installed Ubuntu 10.04. After installation I've updated the system: `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Everything works fine but the Internet connection. It's a wireless connection. Sometimes I can't open any web page even if the connection applet shows "connected". I have to disconnect and connect once again; then it works till the next time it breaks.

Connection is fine, I don't have any problems with that on the other computer. It's also possible it's a hardware problem - the computer is quite old and haven't been used for long time.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Are you still having this problem?    If so, what's your network hardware, and driver?

Comment: How long it remains connected ?  You can also check from a live CD and see if it breaks in between.

Comment: Perhaps if you could open a terminal and type 'lsusb' and 'lspci' and then paste the results back here and then we could see what we can do

Comment: Any useful messages in /var/log/syslog or dmesg?

Comment: I don't know why, but it's first time I see all 4 comments... Anyway, the computer is now completely broken, so the queston will probably rest unsolved. Thank you all anyway and sorry for not posting here but I've just forgot about this post... Should I do something to close the thread?